# I'm trying to make this exercise, all sample entries give the right results except one

Tags: python

[image]

This one is the only one that goes wrong.

Input
The first line of the input consists of an integer NN, indicating the number of cousins of Cacajao.

In the second line, we will have N values ​​ranging from 1 to N, remembering that each monkey has its own value.

Exit
The output consists of a single line containing the number of cousins ​​of Cacajao that are not in their proper place, if all are in their proper place, print “Each mamaco in its place”.

My code

```
x = int(input())
first_list = []
sec_list = input().split()
var = 0
for i in range(1,x+1):
    first_list.append(i)
new_list = [int(t) for t in sec_list]
if sorted(first_list) == new_list:
    print("Each mamaco in its place")
else:
    for k in sec_list:
        if first_list[var] != k:
            var += 1
if var > 0:
    print(var)
```

Answer (score 1):

iterate it's index and compare if sorted list value is same for other list value

```
else:
    for i in range(0,x):
        if first_list[i]!=sec_list[i]:
                var += 1
```

or do it this way, no need of another list.

```
x = int(input())
sec_list = list(map(int,input().split()))
var = 0
for i in range(1,x+1):
    if i!==sec_list[i-1]:
        var += 1
if var > 0:
    print(var)
else
    print("Each mamaco in its place")
```